# Using Python and Json and trying to replace sections

Tags: python, json

I'm using python to try and locate and change different parts of a Json file.

I have a list with 2 columns and what I want to do is look for the string in the first column, find it in the Json file and then replace it with the second column in the list.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this? Been driving me mad.

```
for row in new_list:
    if json_str == new_list[row][0]:
        json_str.replace(new_list[row][0], new_list[row][1])
```

I tried using the .replace() above but it says that it list indices must be integers or slices, not list.

The way that I've managed to print off all the data works...

But this is not referencing anything, so if anyone has any ideas, feel free to lend a hand, thanks.

```
import json

# I import a json file and a text file...

# with open('json file', 'r', encoding="utf8") as jsonData:
#    data = json.load(jsonData)
#    jsonData.close()

jsonData = {"employees":[
    {"firstName":"a"},
    {"firstName":"b"},
    {"firstName":"c"}
]} 

# text_file = open('text file', 'r', encoding="utf8")
# list = text_file.readlines()
# jsonString = str(data)

# The text file contains lots of data like 'a|A', 'b|B, 'c|C'
# so column 1 is lower and column 2 is upper

list = 'a|A, b|B, c|C'

def print_all():   
    for value in list:
        new_list = value.split("|")
        print("%s" % value.split("|"))
        # This prints column 1 and 2

        if new_list[0:] == 'some value':
            print(new_list[1])
            # This prints off the 'replaced' value 

print_all()
```

edit for the comment, this should be able to run... I think

Comment: Could you provide sample input and sample output, and make your code samples complete enough to be runnable (while remaining minimal enough that they contain nothing more than the minimum necessary to provide a runnable, verifiable demonstration of the problem)? See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You should **never** edit JSON strings manually. You will face lots of issues and end up reimplementing a json parser. You need a proper (de)serializer to handle JSON (e.g. `import json`). Unless you can guarantee that the format of the JSON will never change. But even if the format is static then you just make your life horribly difficult. Read the whole file into memory, parse it, update and write it back to the disk. If the file doesn't fit in memory then you should ask yourself: why JSON to begin with? Maybe you should use a proper database? Always pick correct tool for the job.

Comment: Thanks Charles, tried adding more... And I did think that it would be difficult, but it's what I've got to work with unfortunately

Comment: ...so, that's still not a proper MCVE, unless someone can literally copy-and-paste it into their own Python interpreter and have it fail in the same manner you're asking us for help solving -- having it read and write to files that aren't provided or created by code in the question is for obvious reasons a disqualifier on that count. Consider just directly assigning `data={ ...content here... }` and `list=['...content here...']` so no files are needed, and test that you can copy-and-paste it into a brand new Python interpreter yourself and get the same behavior you want our help with.

Comment: Basically, unless the question is complete enough that we can reproduce the same failure you're asking about, we have no way of definitively testing whether an answer actually solves your problem.

Comment: it's awkward to put it in because as freakish said we shouldn't really use the json, but i've tried changing it again, if it's right then hallelujah hahaa

Answer (score 0):

Without more context it's hard to say for sure, but it sounds as though what you want is to use

```
for row in range(len(new_list)):
```

instead of

```
for row in new_list:
```

Comment: I've tried adding some more context, not sure if it's what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

If your JSON file is small enough, just read it into memory and then `.replace()` in a loop.

```
#UNTESTED
with open('json.txt') as json_file:
    json_str = json_file.read()
for was, will_be in new_list:
    json_str = json_str.replace(was, will_be)
with open('new-json.txt', 'w') as json_file:
    json_file.write(json_str)
```

Comment: did try writing to memory but for some reason it wouldn't work, kept saying it needed integers or index?